# Remove specific folder from URL htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have changed URL structure and I want to do the following:
User visits `/p/Rounders/Rounders-84-Backstopping`
301 Redirect to `/Rounders/Rounders-84-Backstopping`

However, we do have other URLs that this shouldn't affect, so it needs to check for `/p/` present in the URL.

Any ideas for the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```